# Issue with D3.JS and Flask-trying to get map of U.S

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js, flask

I am working on a project using D3.JS and Flask trying to display a map of the U.S. The problem is that the map is not displaying. I know that that the SVG element is being attached, that the json data is coming through but the map itself is not coming up. I then tried to create a simple index.html document and placed the json file within that project and using a Python simple server was able to see the map. So now for the code.

To start here is the JS code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    //Define default path generator
    let path = d3.geo.path();

    //Creating the SVG element and attaching it to the page.
    let svg = d3.select("#us-map")
       .append("svg")
       .attr("width", 900)
       .attr("height", 700);

     //This function will get the data for the map of the U.S
     d3.json("/json", function(json){
         console.log(json.features) //This shows an array of 52 objects
         //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
         svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(json.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path);
         });

     </script>
```

Python code:

```
@app.route("/json")
def json():
    data = Data()
    data_file = data.convert_json_for_d3()
    #return data_file
    return data_file.to_json()
```

The method in the class that I am calling from the above code:

```
  def convert_json_for_d3(self):
    self.__data = pd.read_json('us-states.json')
    df = self.__data
    return df
```

The HTML:

```
<section id="us-map">
    <h1>UFO Sitings in the U.S.</h1>
</section>
```

I have been working on this for a day now. At first, getting the json data working with the D3 was the hard part. I figured I had it at that point. However, as I stated, the map is not showing up. It does work if I place it into a simple index.html file along with the json. So I am wondering if the issue is with Flask? One final point, I am following along code from the book Interactive data visualization for the Web. The github repo that I was pulling code from is here: https://github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/blob/master/chapter_12/01_paths.html

Working with a simple HTML file that data appears as this:

```
        object {type: "FeatureCollection", features: Array(52)}
           features:Array(52)
             0:Object
               geometry: Object
                 coordinates: Array(1)
                  0: Array (33)
                   0
                   1
                   :
            1:Object
            :

Data in my Flask Project looks like this:
Object {features: Object, type: Object}
   features: Object
       0: Object 
         geometry: Object
          coordinates: Array(1)
             0: Array (33)

            0:Array(2)
   1: Object
   :
```

So both the array of objects are almost identical-except for the very first line.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues (based on comments below and updated question)

One is the geojson in your Flask project is not valid. For example features should be an array - not an object, type should still be featureCollection (This is discussed in the comments below). Somewhere along the line your geojson structure is changed to something that isn't accepted by d3.geo.path() as valid geojson.

Two is that you are not using a projection to convert your latitude and longitude pairs (in the geometry of each feature) to svg coordinate space.

For the second issue:

When using `d3.geo.path();` you need to specify a projection (eg: `d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator());`). If you do not provide a projection, a null projection is used. This interprets the provided geojson without applying any transformation - essentially your values are translated into pixel values on the svg.

The United States is in the western hemisphere, all the longitudes are therefore negative (and as north south geographic values increase as one goes north and `svg` y values increase as one moves down, the image will be upside down).  A null projection (with no other transform on the `svg`) will draw a path that is to the left of your `svg`'s boundaries. This is why these three things can happen:

- the "SVG element is being attached"
- "that the json data is coming through", but
- "the map itself is not [visually] coming up"

The [geojson](https://github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/blob/master/chapter_12/us-states.json) referenced in the chapter you reference is unprojected data - it contains a latitude and longitude pair for each vertex: `[-133.05341,56.125739]`. This is ideal, as a d3.geo.projection takes this type of coordinate, points on a three dimensional ellipsoid, and projects them onto a two dimensional Cartesian plane. *If you had already planar data you would need to use a geo transform*.

So, to visualize your data you will need to select a projection to convert latitude and longitude pairs into appropriate values. [USA albers](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5545680) might be easiest as it is a composite projection that scales down Alaska and moves both Alaska and Hawaii closer to the continental US. The Albers USA also sets all the projection parameters to show the US without modification to projection parameters (center, rotation, parallels, scale etc), while other projections will require setting proper parameters.

I got your data to display with an albersUsa projection using the following code:

```
var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa().translate([width/2,height/2]);

var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

d3.json("us.json",function(data) {

    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr('d',path)
      .attr('fill','steelblue')
      .attr('stroke','black');

});
```

[Here](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/61f0b6f4d511ea7fc2a082a5279484d7) is a working demo and a screen shot:

[image]

If your map is too large for your svg (or vice versa), you can set the scale with projection.scale(n), with smaller numbers zooming out, larger numbers zooming in.

Comment: Andrew thank you for the information! I can get it to display outside of my Flask project as well. The problem is that it is not displaying in my Flask project. I tried pasting your code in and got the same problem-the SVG is there, the data is there but no map :( . Like I can take my code, as if,  paste it into an HTML file, run a Python simple server and it works fine. It is almost as if there is an issue with Flask-which makes no sense at all to me. When I console.log my data I see the array with 52 objects. But I think you are right that the map is there but not showing up!

Comment: Just to be clear, I did use your code in my project and same issue! :(

Comment: Darn, projection issues are generally why elements appear in the DOM but do not visually appear with d3 (when dealing with geographic data) - but I'll leave this up for a few minutes to see if it helps anyone else get to an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I thought your answer was super useful and I will be using that knowledge in the future! What I can see, and was not able to see before, is the <path fill="steelblue" stroke="black"></path> But that is it within the SVG.

Comment: That would suggest that the json isn't loaded possibly as otherwise it should have some path data (I did change the file name in my code (my bad) - it's probably not the cause of any new problems, but worth a check).

Comment: Yeah, this is what the data looks like in yours: object {type: "FeatureCollection", features: Array(52)} and in mine: object {features: Object, type: Object} not sure if that matters-I can break it up in my original description above

Comment: hmm, very odd. The only potential debugging help I can think of is using this `.attr('d',function(d) { console.log(d); return path(d) })` instead of `.attr('d',path)`. But otherwise, I think I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Yeah, doing the .attr('d',function(d) { console.log(d); return path(d) }) shows the object again-in both cases. Just makes no sense why the map is not appearing on the Flask project, only difference is that first line in the array of objects.

Comment: One last comment (possibly not) - regarding the data: object {features: Object, type: Object}  isn't valid geojson as far as I know - features must be an array for example (not an object), and as you note, the first line is different as well. I think these structural changes are your likely cause of problems.

Comment: Yeah that is the only thing that I can think of as well Andrew, looks like I need to look into a geojson conversion on the python side. I am just using a read_json method from Pandas-Pythons data science library. Thank you for the help though Andrew! I do appreciate it!

Comment: Andrew! I got it! I used the gpd.read_file method after installing geopandas! Thank you for your help with this! (I could see a very small map since I had  projection set to 10! Moved it to larger numbers and the map grow larger!)

Comment: Great, glad I could help a bit - I'll update the answer to touch on the geojson formatting, but still include the geo.projection info - as geographic data requires a projection (generally).